# Object also moves up when moving left and right

Tags: objects

Why does the object move up slowly when moving it left or right?
Its the same in Unity.

[image]

For example the left stick cant reach the upper stick, keep in mind all the sticks are same height

[image]

The picture up shows the right side, it shows that its the same thing, even I can see the upper stick moving up when I move it to any side, but I cant really find any video option so the only thing I can show are images.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/2kod2doc3y8kjez/mansion.blend/file

Comment: the selected object is rotated by 90.6186 degree. This is creates the gap. You can fix it in the side panel (N). Just enter 90 degree for the X rotation.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try and see if it works.

Comment: it worked! thanks.